# Why does UIImage goes beyond UIImageView?

Tags: ios, swift

I am currently loading UIImages in my table view, but the problem is that all UIImages go beyond UIImageView. In fact, their height is equal to the height of the cell.

I did some research and I found out I have to set `clipsToBounds = true` but nothing have changed.

When I set in table cellForRowAt IndexPath the imageView of the cell to an image saved locally, everything is okay.

Here is the function where I get my UIImages array from PFFiles with `getDataInBackground`.

```
func getImagesArray() {
    UIImagesArray.removeAll()

    for i in 0..<self.imagesArray.count { // imagesArray is the PFFile array
        self.imagesArray[i].getDataInBackground(block: { (data, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error?.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                if let imageData = data {
                    if let imageToDisplay = UIImage(data: imageData) {
                        self.UIImagesArray.append(imageToDisplay)

                        if self.imagesArray.count == self.UIImagesArray.count {
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the cellForRowAt if needed:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "userCell", for: indexPath) as! feedUserCellTableViewCell

    cell.imageView!.image = UIImagesArray[indexPath.row]

    cell.username.text! = self.usernamesArray[indexPath.row]

    cell.age.text! = String(self.agesArray[indexPath.row])

    cell.country.text! = self.countriesArray[indexPath.row]

    cell.countryFlagImageView.image! = self.getCoutryImageView(country: self.countriesArray[indexPath.row])

    if self.sexArray[indexPath.row] == "Male" {

        cell.sexImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "male")

    } else if self.sexArray[indexPath.row] == "Female" {

        cell.sexImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "female")

    }

    cell.selectionStyle = .none

    return cell

}
```

Could you explain me this error, why does the `getDataInBackground` provoke this error?

Comment: @Sh_Khan I just edited the post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you have a custom cell in which you are using the cell's built-in `imageView` to display the image. Don't do that.

- Make your *own* image view, give it an outlet with a different name (*not* `imageView`).
- Give it *constraints* so that it cannot grow. (An image view "wants" to grow to the size of its image, so you need to prevent that with a full set of constraints.)
- Make sure its content mode is `aspectFill` or `aspectFit`.
- Make sure its `clipsToBounds` is `true` (by default, it is *not*).

Comment: and you're right, it is fixed ! thank you very much !

Comment: Thank you! This saves my life! I have spent 1 hour to figure out why the image is beyond the bounce of imageView, since it is 100% coding way, I used custom cell too, after checking all the constraints, contentMode, clipsToBounds without result. And found this thread, the reason is that I used default name `imageView` too and forgot to used the custom name.